# Query doesnt produce the expected result

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

```
using (Entities PlatfrmName = new Entities())
{
    foreach (string selectedProject in SplitSelectedprojects)
    {
        var platformId = from platformID in PlatfrmName.AppProjects84
                         where platformID.ProjectName == selectedProject
                         select platformID.PlatformId;

                        var platformName = from platfrmName in PlatfrmName.AppPlatforms84
                                           where platfrmName.PlatformId.ToString() == platformId.ToString()
                                           select platfrmName.PlatformName;
                        //Get the projects based on the platforms
                        if (platformName.ToString() == "Base")
                            BASE += selectedProject + ",";
                        if (platformName.ToString() == "Windows")
                            WINDOWS += selectedProject + ",";
                        if (platformName.ToString() == "Web")
                            WEB += selectedProject + ",";
                        if (platformName.ToString() == "Wpf")
                            WPF += selectedProject + ",";
                        if (platformName.ToString() == "Silverlight")
                            SILVERLIGHT += selectedProject + ",";
                        if (platformName.ToString() == "Mvc")
                            MVC += selectedProject + ",";
    }
}
```

I expect the result as `platformName == Base`, then that project should be added to the BASE variable. When the control comes to the  `if (platformName.ToString() == "Base")`, I hover the cursor to that, it shows nothing. can anyone help me out this.

Comment: Watch out for an n+1 database request issue here. Make sure to profile your SQL when you are performing linq queries inside of foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the second query is not an object of Platform but IQueryable. Therefore ToString will not return any of the strings you expect. In addition the second query (and probably the first) is not executed against the database at all since there is nothing that force the execution (i.e. no evaluation). I also believe you can have just one query instead of two. Something like this:

```
var platformName = (from platform in PlatfrmName.AppProjects84 
                   where platformID.ProjectName == selectedProject 
                   select platform.PlatformName).Single();
```

should do the trick - first, it combines two queries. Second, it forces query evaluation by using .Single(). This way the query is sent to the database to get the results. I assume you expect only one result for a given project and hence I used Single(). The result of .Single() is a single object and not IEnumerable so you should be able to get your platformName. Also if the platformName is string you don't have to use .ToString().